# Conditional expressions. Uppercase to lowercase

Tags: c

The following code works:

```
int convert(int s){
    int result = 0;
    result = (s >= 97 && s <= 122)? s -32 : s+32;
    return result;
}
```

However, since a copy of s is used inside the function, can you change the function to the following?

```
int convert(int s){
    (s >= 97 && s <= 122)? s -= 32 : s += 32;
    return s;
}
```

*Is it allowed to assign values in conditional expressions like I did?*

Comment: yes, but consider `islower`, `toupper`, and `s >= 'a'`

Comment: Note that your code also changes `!` (ASCII 33) to `A` (ASCII 65), etc.

Comment: "*However, since a copy of s is used inside the function*" is already your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is allowed because you are editing a local copy of s. See the live example here:

Try this:

```
int convert(int s){
    (s >= 97 && s <= 122)? (s -= 32) : (s += 32);
    return s;
}

int main(void) {

    int val = 10, val2;
    val2 = convert(val);
    printf("%d %d\n", val, val2);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a live example.

http://ideone.com/5aJcOv

Of course you should be using `toupper` and `tolower` in conjunction with `isupper` and `islower` to change the case of the ascii characters:

```
#include <ctype.h>
char toggleCase(char c)
{
    if (c >= 'a') {  // Check that it is a letter
        if (isupper(c)) return tolower(c); //Convert it
        return toupper(c);
    }
    return c; // Otherwise dont 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is allowed. You may try like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    putchar(tolower('A'));
}
```

Comment: When I tried the first one, it tells me: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment +=

Comment: @user3808877 Then you forgot the precedence rules. Put `()` where appropriate.